# How to add speech recognition in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, windows, speech-recognition, visual-studio-2019

I want to make a speech recognition program in C# in visual studio 2019 but I can't figure out how to add the speech library when I click add references, it does not give me the option of adding from assemblies. How do I get the assemblies tab to show up when adding references?

Comment: Hey have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: I've been to that website. My problem is getting the library, I can't find a way to add it to the code.

Comment: use NuGetpackage manager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)

Comment: You can refer to [Speech Recognition with .NET Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/december/voice-recognition-speech-recognition-with-net-desktop-applications) to know how to make a speech recognition program.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Nuget Manager(right click on you project -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Browse -> Search (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) -> Install -> Check Reference in Solution Explorer)

Or

Open Package Manager Console -> And write command for adding packages in you project

```
Install-Package <Package Name>
```

For More Information -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest Microsoft speech platform sdk [here](http://aka.ms/speech/sdk), you can get started very quickly with step-by-step guidance at this page: http://aka.ms/speech/sr-microphone. That includes links that describe how to set up your Visual Studio project in VS 2019 (click on the link titled "Setup your development environment").

--robch